# How to search for C# source code files in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, c#, file-extension

I'm trying to find some lost C# source code files on an old external drive.

I believe the file extension for C# source files is `.cs`.

When I enter in the search file `*.cs` and begin searching, I find that Windows also finds all files whose extension *just begins with* `cs` such as CSS `.css` files.

How can I use Explorer to find *only* `.cs` files and not the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the exact extension you want, surrounded by quotes `"`, eg `"*.cs"`.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of quotes, use the `ext` option. `ext:xls` & so on

Comment: @Sathya That would still return the ones which match beyond the characters you want, no? http://i.imgur.com/hk1cROo.jpg - You could use quotes *and* `ext` though.